# Why empty layers such as LABEL,USER shows size in docker history <image_id>?

Tags: docker, redhat, layer

After pulling standart image (e.g., ubuntu) from docker hub and run "docker history <image_id> provides a detailed info on the layers that builds the image.

```
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
13b66b487594   2 years ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>      2 years ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'do…   7B
<missing>      2 years ago   /bin/sh -c [ -z "$(apt-get indextargets)" ]     0B
<missing>      2 years ago   /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /…   195kB
<missing>      2 years ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:276b5d943a4d284f8…   196MB
```

Pulling image from redhat registry such as `registry.redhat.io/openshift-logging/kibana6-rhel8`
with Dockerfile:
[Dockerfile](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/openshift-logging/kibana6-rhel8/5fd1ffeee4e4bade45665535?container-tabs=dockerfile)

and run "docker history <image_id> command provides the following output:

```
`IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
19f37937750f   5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER 0                        387MB     FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi8@sha256:b6616b280ec23c2283ac10e19dd3cd4c8e6df14599f6d93f662ca261273097a9
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER root                     0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER 0                        0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER root                     0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL "com.redhat.license_…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:87df2e698917ed7ba…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:d466255d32642f4d1…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL release=381             0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL         License="Apa…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["./run.sh"]              0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:bae744ef2f4da932…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:736ef4a8dfbacf87…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:f18f57ea6dabab77…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:486380ed6d35a958…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f5514d63986b5e13d…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:7c32cadf89a8db89e…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:80925afb105d083f4…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ARG REMOTE_SOURCES REMOTE_…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 5601                   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV SOURCE_GIT_URL=${CI_KI…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV SOURCE_GIT_COMMIT=${CI…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV OS_GIT_PATCH=1            0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV OS_GIT_MINOR=8            0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV OS_GIT_MAJOR=6            0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV BUILD_VERSION=6.8.1       0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR ${HOME}               0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER 0                        0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NPM_RUN=start     NAME…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV HOME=/opt/app-root/src    0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NODEJS_VERSION=10         0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:912d8b2f4e297f8b4…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:214c1de395c24e4a8…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   |2 REMOTE_SOURCES=unpacked_remote_sources RE…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ARG REMOTE_SOURCES REMOTE_…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ARG REMOTE_SOURCES            0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mv -fZ /tmp/ubi.repo /etc/yum.rep…   207MB
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c rm -f /tmp/tls-ca-bundle.pem         0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c rm -f '/etc/yum.repos.d/repo-cdf2…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL "distribution-scope"…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f9f7ba78e28f98ff3…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:4eb2d82a9268a2ece…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL release=1032            0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /var/log/rhsm               0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/log/*                    0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV container oci             0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.openshift.tags="b…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.openshift.expose-…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL io.k8s.display-name=…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL description="The Uni…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL summary="Provides th…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL com.redhat.license_t…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL com.redhat.component…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL maintainer="Red Hat,…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD multi:dad1054d72a3e8b4…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:214c1de395c24e4a8…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c mv -f /etc/yum.repos.d/ubi.repo /…   0B
<missing>      5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:66850d5e06c92b821…   0B
`
```

**19f37937750f   5 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) USER 0                        387MB     FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi8@sha256:b6616b280ec23c2283ac10e19dd3cd4c8e6df14599f6d93f662ca261273097a9**

Why does empty layer such as USER which doesn't affect on the file system holds such a big size ? I expected it to be 0.

As described in the above section.

Comment: I suspect this is an artifact of whatever tooling built the image – note that all of the other layers are listed as size zero, even when they obviously `COPY` content into the image.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "artifact of whatever tooling built the image"..
Isn't this the command to build the image ?
It seems like the registry that keeps the image (after pushing), performs several operations that change the layer's real size.